# i want to create a counter which change every time i click on the button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, algorithm

a set a button which create an new div everytime i click on it , every div created must have a new i so i try to create an counter which change every time i click on the button i try a lot of codes but none work correctly , this is the last code i tried

```js
function AddDiv() {
  var i = 0;
  $("#AddDrop").click(function() {
    i++;
  });
  const e = document.createElement('div');
  e.setAttribute('id', i);
  e.style.border = 'solid';
  e.style.width = '300px';
  e.style.height = '100px'
  e.innerHTML = 'Droppable'
  question = document.getElementById("QU");
  question.appendChild(e);
}

function GetText() {
  const event = document.createElement('div')
  const text = document.getElementById("in").value;
  event.innerHTML = text;
  question = document.getElementById("QU");
  question.appendChild(event);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <textarea id="in" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></textarea>
      <br>
      <button onclick="GetText();" class="btn btn-primary">Add Text</button>
      <button onclick="AddDiv();" class="btn btn-success" id="AddDrop">Add div</button>
      <input type="file" accept="image/*" value="Add Images" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="QU" style="border: solid; height: 600px;">

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `var i = 0;` needs to be outside the function. Otherwise it's set back to 0 every time you click.

Comment: If my answer helped you, it would be great if you could accept and upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AddDiv()` function, you are always resetting `i` to 0, which means every time that you run the function, it's going to be one all over again. You need to take it out of the function to keep it counting.

Comment: You should also mention that assigning clicks all over again (inside the `addDiv()`) is just purely wrong. (it should also go out of that function.) Also OP should not use unsafe inline `on*` handlers. JS should be in one place only and that's the respective tag or file. Your answer is in the right direction, but far from the best. You should also mention that `innerHTML` should be **never used** in that way, passing unsanitized user inputs strings and placing them into a HTML document.